# Toplink IN subquery

Tags: java, jpa, subquery, jpql, toplink

I hava 2 objects associate by oneToMany relationship("One Model can have many events").

I'm trying to make a subquery in ejbql to find models for one event, like this:

```
SELECT model 
FROM RegModelValue model 
WHERE :event IN (model.events)
```

....
but toplink doent recognize model alias and tell me "Internal Exception: line 1:129: unexpected token: model"

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot by advance !

Answer (score 0):

I think the order is wrong, the `:event` cannot be before a `IN`.

Try this :

```
    SELECT model 
    FROM RegModelValue model 
    JOIN model.events events
    WHERE events.id = :event
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but, I test it and it doesn't work.
"events" is a list and I think Toplink doesn't like the syntaxe "events.id".
For the moment I made a native sql query to solve problem but I let you know if I find an issus for this query.
Anyway, thank you for spending some time on this answer !

Comment: @ajeason I'm not sure for ejbql actually, I only know for Hibernate HQL. In "events.id", the "id" stands for the primary key for the table. If your primary key column is called pk_event, it could be "events.pk_event". (I put "id" because HQL have "id" as a generic shortcut for the primary key, but I think this behavior is not portable to ejbql.)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will reste it (when have some time...)
I let you know for the Toplink syntaxe !

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for your JPQL query should be:

```
SELECT model 
FROM RegModelValue model 
WHERE model.events IN (:event)
```

Below, the relevant section of the JPA 1.0 specification:

> #### 4.6.8 In Expressions
>
> The syntax for the use of the
>   comparison operator [NOT] IN in a
>   conditional expression is as follows:
>
> ```
> in_expression ::=
>     state_field_path_expression [NOT] IN ( in_item {, in_item}* | subquery)
> in_item ::= literal | input_parameter
> ```
>
> The *state_field_path_expression*
>   must have a string, numeric, or enum
>   value. The literal and/or
>   input_parameter values must be like
>   the same abstract schema type of the
>   *state_field_path_expression* in type. (See Section 4.12).
>
> The results of the subquery must be
>   like the same abstract schema type of
>   the *state_field_path_expression* in
>   type. Subqueries are discussed in
>   Section 4.6.15, “Subqueries”.
>
> Examples are:
>
> `o.country IN (’UK’, ’US’, ’France’)`
>   is true for `UK` and false for `Peru`,
>   and is equivalent to the expression
>   `(o.country = ’UK’) OR (o.country =
>   ’US’) OR (o.country = ’ France’)`.
>
> `o.country NOT IN (’UK’, ’US’,
>   ’France’)` is false for `UK` and true
>   for `Peru`, and is equivalent to the
>   expression `NOT ((o.country = ’UK’) OR
>   (o.country = ’US’) OR (o.country =
>   ’France’))`.
>
> There must be at least one element in
>   the comma separated list that defines
>   the set of values for the IN
>   expression.
>
> If the value of a
>   *state_field_path_expression* in an IN or NOT IN expression is `NULL` or
>   unknown, the value of the expression
>   is unknown.